# Javascript: Accessing the value of a dynamic key embedded inside a dynamic key

Tags: javascript, json

i have an object whose structure look like `{sessionID: {Symbol: response {}}}` where sessionID and Symbol are dynamic keys.. i’m trying to access the value of the Symbol which is **response** in this case… so i tried something like `object[sessionID].Symbol`, `object[sessionID].object[Symbol]`, `object[sessionID.Symbol]`, `object[sessionID[Symbol]]` but nothing worked, is there a way to access the value of a dynamic key embedded inside another dynamic key

Comment: is your key **Symbol** will repeat inside seesionID? like 
`{sessionID: {Symbol: response {},Symbol: response {}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) to access properties by identifiers, [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) expects a string:

```
object.sessionID.Symbol
```

or

```
object['sessionID']['Symbol']
```

If `sessionID` and `Symbol` are variables containing strings (or [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)) then you can use:

```
object[sessionID][Symbol]
```

Comment: this one worked object[sessionID][Symbol], thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this notation

```
var key1 = "sessionID";
var key2 = "Symbol";

object[key1][key2];
```

Where `key1` and `key2` are your dynamic keys

Answer (score 0):

say `obj = {sessionID: {Symbol: response {}}}`
we can do

```
for(var key1 in obj){
 var session = obj[key1];
 for(var key2 in session){
   console.log(session[key2]); //prints response
 }
}
```